# Calling a WebAssembly library like CanvasKit from my own WebAssembly module

Tags: webassembly, canvaskit

I find a lot of code written in Javascript showing how to use CanvasKit. But I'd like to write my own C++ code, using some features of CanvasKit, to write a custom WebAssembly module that I can use from JS. Is it possible?

I'm new to WebAssembly, but not to C++ and JS. I looked for some examples or resources regarding using CanvasKit in combination with a hand-made Wasm module but could not find anything. Maybe am I missing the right keywords?